# Cannot specify link libraries for target "node_name" which is not built by this project

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use opencv on kinetic. As per [4.1](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython)
on this wiki, I had to add a dependency on opencv2 and find_package in the CMakeLists.txt [instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv)].

This is my edited CMakeList.txt. I'm getting

```
 'CMake Error at pc_side/CMakeLists.txt:19 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "pc_side" which is not built by
  this project.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/raspi/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/raspi/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:906: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pc_side)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  sensor_msgs
  cv_bridge
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(pc_side ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

catkin_package()
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332121/cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-%22node_name%22-which-is-not-built-by---this-project./) by [nav3128](https://answers.ros.org/users/45318/nav3128/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-09-01**:
Please post the full error output copied from your terminal, not just the main error text.

**Comment by [nav3128](https://answers.ros.org/users/45318/nav3128/) on 2019-09-02**:
I've edited the question to show the full error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `target_link_libraries` tag is used to add the library dependencies of a specific binary (executable or library) that is built in the package, not the package as a whole.

If your trying to use OpenCV 2 on ROS kinetic it's already included, adding a dependency on the cv_bridge package should be all you need to do. Then you just need to add the correct header files and start using OpenCV in your code.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1